# Highlighting today's date in python using calendar.py in command prompt/windows powershell

Tags: python, powershell, dictionary, cmd, calendar

I ran the following .py file using window's command prompt.

```
def main():
import calendar
from datetime import date
import time

# Converting 'datetime.date object to a string'
today=str(date.today())
# Generating a list of string like ['2021', '02', '02']
today=today.split("-")
#Converting string to integer
year=int(today[0])
month=int(today[1])
date=int(today[2])
print(calendar.month(year,month))

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

It gave me the following output.

[image]

If I wanted to highlight today's date in windows command prompt like shown below, what would I have to do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can apply [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting), e.g. as follows:

```
from datetime import date
import calendar
import time
import re

today = date.today()
year  = today.year
month = today.month
thism = calendar.month(year,month)    # current month
date  = today.day.__str__().rjust(2)
rday  = ('\\b' + date + '\\b').replace('\\b ', '\\s')
rdayc = "\033[7m" + date + "\033[0m"
#             7 Swaps foreground and background colors
print( re.sub(rday,rdayc,thism))
```

Works from `cmd`, `powershell` and `pwsh` regardless if run under `conhost.exe` or from Windows Terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import calendar
from datetime import date


class DayInMonthHighlightingCalendar(calendar.TextCalendar):
    def __init__(self, day_to_highlight):
        super().__init__()
        self._day_to_highlight = day_to_highlight

    def formatday(self, day: int, weekday: int, width: int) -> str:
        s = super().formatday(day, weekday, width)
        if day == self._day_to_highlight:
            s = f"\033[7m{s}\033[0m"
        return s


today = date.today()
year, month, day, *_ = today.timetuple()

DayInMonthHighlightingCalendar(day_to_highlight=day).prmonth(year, month)
```

I used @JosefZ's answer and introduced a subclass of the TextCalendar.

The final effect is the same, but the code structure should be a bit clearer.